# CSS/HTML border radius issue with fixed backgrounds in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, background

I do not really understand what happens with some basic HTML/CSS code:

The HTML:

```
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    hello
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.class1
{
  height:300px;
  background: url('https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/kartandtinki1_photo-wallpapers_02.jpg') center no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  padding:60px;
}

.class2
{
  background: url('https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/i-should-buy-a-boat.jpg') center no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  border-radius: 100px;
  line-height:100px;
  color:white;
}
```

I also did a codepen to "show it live", [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNxKYz).

My issue is that I get some strange "black" at the border radius, and I do not know why. Here are some pics:

[image: Expected] [image: Unexpected]

At the left I get the expected result with IE11, but at the left I get a strange result with Firefox (latest vers.).

My question is, how can I fix this so both browsers show me the result at the left picture (i.e. get rid of the black)?

Thanks!

Comment: With Firefox 42 I see no issue. However, with Firefox 43.0.1 and 44.0.2 I do. Interesting.

Comment: This is due to a bug in Firefox. It seems `background-attachment:fixed` is what's causing this.

Comment: Strange, I'm seeing the same, but it's white, not black. But I agree with @agrm, must be a bug. I'd [file a bug with Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/). Have a look to see if there's a bug filed relating to this already though.

Comment: I see, my restricted experience with html/css made me unsure, so if that's a bug I guess that's different. I'd still be interested in a workaround if ever someone finds one. Pretty funny for once my IE11 was correct and not Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .class1 {
            height:969px;
            background: url('https://d19m59y37dris4.cloudfront.net/directory/1-3/img/photo/photo-1501621965065-c6e1cf6b53e2.jpg');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: 100% 100%;
            background-attachment:fixed;
            padding:60px;
        }
        .class2 {
            background: url('https://d19m59y37dris4.cloudfront.net/directory/1-3/img/photo/new-york.jpg');
            background-size: 100% 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            border-radius: 100px;
            line-height:100px;
            color:white;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="class1">
        <div class="class2">hello</div>
    </div>
```